# E: Error install python3 pip

Tags: package-management, software-installation, dpkg

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
[sudo] password for it: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done

Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.

The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gsettings-desktop-schemas : Breaks: mutter (< 3.31.4) but 3.28.4+git20200505-0ubuntu18.04.2 is to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Comment: You've provided little detail; I'd firstly like to know your release (you haven't told us, your messages imply *bionic* but assumptions don't help fix problems as the package shown in the message maybe the result of a message up source & thus needs to be compared with what release you believe you have installed)... I'd `sudo apt update` to ensure it's clean without issues firstly.. but knowing your release is needed first.

Answer (score 1):

Try running the following:

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
sudo aptitude install python3-pip
```

Comment: it works, thank you..